# Differing Sha1 Result between Node & Python

Tags: python, node.js, sha

I'm currently trying to implement a call to the Royal Mail API usingNodeJs and SOAP; I'm having difficulty recreating the security headers implementation following an example python script

The python script is as follows

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import os
import sha
import binascii
import base64

password = 'test'
CREATIONDATE =  '2016-03-29T14:03:46Z'
nonce =  '7715776714'
HASH = sha.new(password).digest()
BASE64PASSWORD = base64.b64encode(HASH)

digest = sha.new(nonce + CREATIONDATE + HASH).digest()


PASSWORDDIGEST = base64.b64encode(digest)
ENCODEDNONCE = base64.b64encode(nonce)

print 'NONCE = ', nonce
print 'BASE64PASSWORD', BASE64PASSWORD
print 'PASSWORDDIGEST ', PASSWORDDIGEST
print 'ENCODEDNONCE ', ENCODEDNONCE
print 'CREATIONDATE ', CREATIONDATE
```

Which outputs:

```
NONCE  7715776714  
BASE64PASSWORD qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M=  
PASSWORDDIGEST  coDzcnSZObFfrM0FY33GcfxjOj4=  
ENCODEDNONCE NzcxNTc3NjcxNA==  
CREATIONDATE 2016-03-29T14:03:46Z
```

I've re-created this using NodeJs but I seem to get a differing output - inputting the correct password in the python version and using the resulting data allows me to make a valid call to the API, using the output from NodeJs gives me an authorisation failure

**Node Js Code**

```
var createdDate, password = 'test', nonce;
createdDate = '2016-03-29T14:03:46Z';
nonce = '7715776714';

var crypto = require("crypto"),
passHash = crypto.createHash('sha1'),
digestHash = crypto.createHash('sha1');

passHash.update(password);

var HASH = passHash.digest();
console.log('NONCE ' + nonce)
console.log('BASE64PASSWORD ' + base64_encode_string(HASH))

digestHash.update(nonce + createdDate + HASH);
var digest = digestHash.digest();

var PASSWORDDIGEST = base64_encode_string(digest);
console.log('PASSWORDDIGEST ' + PASSWORDDIGEST);
var ENCODEDNONCE = base64_encode_string(nonce.toString());

console.log('ENCODEDNONCE ' + ENCODEDNONCE);
console.log('CREATIONDATE ' + createdDate);
```

Which outputs

```
NONCE 7715776714  
BASE64PASSWORD qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M=  
PASSWORDDIGEST FRMDpkDOi1j9KB/sDHg1b7BYQgA=  
ENCODEDNONCE NzcxNTc3NjcxNA==  
CREATIONDATE 2016-03-29T14:03:46Z
```

It appears that the Sha for the HASH is identical but the second Sha (digest) gives a differing result in the NodeJs version. Any pointers to where I'm going wrong?

For reference I'm using sha library in python and crypto in NodeJs

Comment: `sha` module is deprecated, it might be wise to use `hashlib` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you're implicitly converting the `HASH` Buffer to a UTF-8 string which is liable to cause corrupt output when converting binary to UTF-8. Instead, you can call `.update()` multiple times and preserve the binary data in `HASH`:

```
digestHash.update(nonce + createdDate);
digestHash.update(HASH);
var digest = digestHash.digest();
```

On an unrelated note, you don't need `base64_encode_string()` for Buffers, as for those you can simply do `buffer.toString('base64')` (e.g. `HASH.toString('base64')`).